# Player for iPhone Programming?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sdk, avaudioplayer

I am using `AVAudioPlayer` in my program, but having touble in something

I have 10 sounds, and as I click one to play or then others don't stop, I tried to solve by

```
[myPlayer stop];
myPlayer = nil;
```

it works, but takes time, so what should I do to stop when it click 2nd row on tableview for playing another sound?

If any query regarding question, you may ask in comments,

Comment: @7KV7, thnx for editing, now is there any answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think You hae added some observer before calling, [myPlayer play];... So you have to remove those observer

Comment: is there no any alternative and faster way?

Comment: I solved the problem dear, there was some issue of re-initializing the same objects and call play and stop(was working for current object), so I declare BOOL and check conditions, and solved the problem.